# How to send an email through Titanium mobile application

Tags: titanium

How to send an email through Titanium mobile application.
I am receiving error of "localhost denied"

Comment: Do you use an email dialog to send the email?

Comment: No i am not using it. I just want to send an email from a titamiun mobile app. without dialog

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you use something like `mailto:email@mydomain.com`.

You should be using e-mail dialog: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog-object

This should work for you.

```
var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog()
emailDialog.subject = "Hello from Titanium";
emailDialog.toRecipients = ['foo@yahoo.com'];
emailDialog.html = '<b>Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!</b>';
emailDialog.open();
```

If you want to send an e-mail without a dialog, try doing an AJAX call to a webserver, and then sending it on the server.

Sending it on the phone without dialog is not possible.

Comment: please tell me ,actually I just want to send an email from a titamiun mobile app. without dialog

Comment: Then you should do an AJAX call to a server which sends the email

Answer (score 0):

This pizza ordering app tutorial sends an email based on the users selection.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-build-a-pizza-ordering-app/

Answer (score 0):

```
  var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();

   emailDialog.subject = "Checkout this Mail";
   emailDialog.toRecipients = ['ebrahim.3bmo3ty@gmail.com'];
   emailDialog.setMessageBody("we sending email here");
   emailDialog.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this one:-**

```
 mail.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

 var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();

    if (!emailDialog.isSupported()) {
        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title:'Error',
            message:'Email not available on this device.'
        }).show();
        return;
    }

    emailDialog.setSubject(' Gmail !!!!!!!! ');
    emailDialog.setToRecipients(['abc@gmail.com']);
    emailDialog.setMessageBody('Hi,\n I am working with appcelerator.');
    emailDialog.setHtml(false);
    emailDialog.setBarColor('#336699');

   emailDialog.addEventListener('complete',function(e){
            if (e.result == emailDialog.SENT){
                if (Ti.Platform.osname != 'android'){
                        alert("message was sent");
                }
            }else{
                alert("message was not sent. " );
            }
    });
}
```

Spartacus Thanks :)